# Autofocus on MazPhoneNumberInput Vue.js

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

I'm using MazPhoneNumberInput component ( https://maz-ui.com/components/maz-phone-number-input ) in my form this way:

```
<MazPhoneNumberInput
    v-model="phoneNumber"
    v-model:country-code="countryCode"
    show-code-on-list
    :preferred-countries="['DE', 'US', 'GB']"
    noFlags
    />
```

and would like to set autofocus on phone input.

MazPhoneNumberInput component doesn't have autofocus prop itself, but it based on MazInput component ( https://maz-ui.com/components/maz-input ), which has autofocus prop:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8Ynd.png)

I tried to set focus via javascript with onMounted method:

```
import AppLayout from "@/Layouts/Auth/AppLayout.vue";
import MazPhoneNumberInput from 'maz-ui/components/MazPhoneNumberInput'
import {ref, onMounted} from 'vue'

const phoneNumber = ref()
const countryCode = ref('DE')

const focusInput = () => {
    phoneNumber.value.focus();
};

onMounted(focusInput);
```

but it didn't work.

How can I set autofocus on my phone input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using a [template ref](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs) which gives access to the DOM element of the component.  Since the root element is just a wrapper around multiple other elements, an additional query will be necessary to grab the actual telephone input which you can then focus:

```html
<MazPhoneNumberInput
  ref="phone"
  v-model="phoneNumber"
  v-model:country-code="countryCode"
  show-code-on-list
  :preferred-countries="['DE', 'US', 'GB']"
  no-flags
/>
```

```js
const phone = ref();

onMounted(async () => {
  const phoneEl = phone.value.$el // MazPhoneNumberInput root DOM element
  const phoneInput = phoneEl.querySelector('input[type=tel]') // inner input DOM element

  await nextTick() // can focus after next DOM update
  phoneInput.focus()
})
```

Comment: yoduh, thank you very much for answer! Using your code I'm getting an error "Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: phone is not defined". When I changed "phone" to "phoneNumber" in second line, the error is "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '$el')"

Comment: My mistake, I forgot to include the updated template code and necessary `phone` ref initialization, `const phone = ref();`.  I've updated the answer